# How do I reference a "subset" or cells in an Excel Named Range?

Tags: excel, named-ranges

I have a named range in Excel (that was created do to making a Web Query in Excel)... how do I get the sum of just the "Amount" column?

Example: This works: =SUM(MyRange)

The problem is, that sums EVERY numeric looking field (so "Amount" and "UserID" are BOTH being included in the SUM function).

What I need is this: =SUM(MyRange["Amount"]) ... but I can't seem to find how to do something like that.

Thoughts?

Comment: Good question... I should have mentioned - Excel 2007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: The DSUM formula (Database SUM):

=DSUM(MyRange,"Amount",MyRange)

Basically, it's just summing the 'Amount' field in the database 'MyRange'.

Bill

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [offset() function](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/offset.php) if you know where the Amount column is relative to the named range.

Comment: To retrieve first cell. OFFSET(MyNamedRange,0,0,1,1)